# android database altering a table than adding a fixed value to all rows?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

<s>I have a table in my android app that is very simple. Has an id and a few longs/ints for values. I haven't updated my app in a while but I am working on a huge, totally revamped version. I thought about making the app completely independent of the original one but that would potentially disappoint current users. Instead, I'll make it as a big upgrade off the last iteration. I'm wondering whether I should copy all of the data to a new table and trash the old one or just modify the schema of the existing table and avoid having to delete?</s>

Another question I have is....if I were to go about doing either of these tasks, how would I do so WITH fixed, predetermined values for the new entries in all of the rows corresponding with the original table? I guess it may be hard to understand what I'm truly asking. Let's say I want a value of "5" added to every row a new column in a table already made. Can I easily go about doing so? If so, how?

**EDIT:**
I'm gonna be a lot more specific and provide you with what I really want to do. I have 1 table. Let's call it Z. Z consists of an autoincrement int primary key, int date, numeric price, numeric length, and numeric amount. I will add another table, X, which will have an autoincrement int primary key, and a string value for the name. In table Z, I want to add the attributes: int type, and int x_id (this will link to the string in the X table). How would I go about ALTERING my original table Z using onUpgrade() then populate the new attributes (type and x_id) with 2 variables (in Java)?

Comment: You're not talking about local storage, right? You're talking about your database in the cloud?

Comment: local storage, in /data/data/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your table's layout or create a new one depends on the actual changes and your personal preferences, there is no general answer to that question.

You can do all necessary upgrades/migration tasks in the **onUpgrade** Method of you **SQLiteOpenHelper** subclass(es)

Comment: Yeah, I think I'll add columns to the existing table since it shouldn't be a lot of data (for any of my users) but I'm still wondering how to do the 2nd part?

Comment: @BackpackOnHead Increase the db version you pass to the constructor of SQLiteOpenHelper. You have both, the old version and the new version available in the onUpgrade Method then. Change your tables with ALTER TABLE... etc. there based on old and new version

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Just not sure how to do the second part of my question.

Comment: You have the db object as parameter in the onUpgrade Method, so you can select the data, change it, and write it back with UPDATE/INSERT